# Formula for changing displayed date in looker studio field?

Tags: google-bigquery, looker-studio, looker

I am quite new into looker studio. I have made a chart that displays data week per week. The dimension used for this is ISO year week. The problem is that I would like the header field to just be Week 51, Week 52..., are there a formula for this or another way?

[Image of table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t69eY.png)

Have tried out several Extract and Truncate combinations, but I think I simply don't understand the formulas well enough to get the solution i expected. Found this formula extracts week but keeps days: EXTRACT(Date FROM DATETIME_TRUNC(Date, WEEK))

Answer (score 0):

It is nice and simple :)

Add a field called week number and use this formula

```
WEEK(YourDateField, 1)
```

It calculates the week number, considering Monday as the start of the week (change the number to change the day of the week).

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I get something that looks like this
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmFNi.png